# Installing xgboost in PyCharm on MAC - Error occured when installing package 'xgboost'

Tags: python, pycharm, package, xgboost

I'm having trouble installing `xgboost` in PyCharm.

I have downloaded and installed Anaconda and ran the following commands in the Terminal:

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

```
conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost
```

When I try to

```
import xgboost as xgb
```

within PyCharm, it tells me that there's no module named `xgboost`.

And when trying to install `xgboost` via Preferences -> Interpreter, I get the following error:
`Error occured when installing package 'xgboost'`

What am I doing wrong?

I get the following `'Proposed solution': Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/Users/xxxxxx/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/bin/python'`.

I don't understand the solution entirely?

Comment: You could try to install `xgboost` via pip/pip3. Activate your conda environment in the terminal and run `pip install xgboost`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! what does it mean to 'activate the conda environment in the terminal'? I'm sorry, I'm not very experienced with Python. I've actually tried the `pip install xgboost` command in the terminal but maybe I need to activate the conda environment as you say, I just don't know how to do it so I would appreciate some help!

Comment: This is what I get when the using the `pip install xgboost` command:
`Requirement already satisfied: xgboost in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from xgboost) (1.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from xgboost) (1.5.2)`

Comment: To activate a conda environment you can run [`conda activate <env_name>`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) where `<env_name>`  is the name of your environment. After that you should see `(env_name)` in your prompt. Using `pip` you can then install `xgboost` for this specific environment. To confirm it worked, you can run the python interpreter in your terminal and `import xgboost`.

Comment: Thanks! what exactly is the 'name of my environment'? I know this is probably a stupid question, but like I said I'm not very experienced with coding...